# Node.js buf.toString vs String.fromCharCode

Tags: node.js, character-encoding

I'm attempting to display the character `í` from `0xed` (237).

`String.fromCharCode` yields the correct result:

```
String.fromCharCode(0xed); // 'í'
```

However, when using a `Buffer`:

```
var buf = new Buffer(1);
buf.writeUInt8(0xed,0); // <Buffer ed>
buf.toString('utf8'); // '?', same as buf.toString()
buf.toString('binary'); // 'í'
```

Using 'binary' with `Buffer.toString` is to be [deprecated](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) so I want to avoid this.

Second, I can also expect incoming data to be multibyte (i.e. UTF-8), e.g.:

```
String.fromCharCode(0x0512); // Ԓ - correct
var buf = new Buffer(2);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x0512,0); // <Buffer 12 05>, [0x0512 & 0xff, 0x0512 >> 8]
buf.toString('utf8'); // Ԓ - correct
buf.toString('binary'); // Ô
```

Note that both examples are inconsistent.

SO, what am I missing? What am I assuming that I shouldn't? Is `String.fromCharCode` magical?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you might be assuming that `String`s and `Buffer`s use the same bit-length and encoding.

JavaScript `String`s are [16-bit, UTF-16 sequences](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.16) while Node's `Buffer`s are 8-bit sequences.

UTF-8 is also a variable byte-length encoding, with code points consuming [between 1 and 6 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). The UTF-8 encoding of `í`, for example, takes 2 bytes:

```
> new Buffer('í', 'utf8')
<Buffer c3 ad>
```

And, on its own, `0xed` is not a valid byte in UTF-8 encoding, thus the `?` representing an "unknown character." It is, however, a valid UTF-16 code for use with `String.fromCharCode()`.

Also, the output you suggest for the 2nd example doesn't seem correct.

```
var buf = new Buffer(2);
buf.writeUInt16LE(0x0512, 0);
console.log(buf.toString('utf8')); // "\u0012\u0005"
```

You can detour with `String.fromCharCode()` to see the UTF-8 encoding.

```
var buf = new Buffer(String.fromCharCode(0x0512), 'utf8');
console.log(buf); // <Buffer d4 92>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of s4.3.16, so thanks for that. It turns out I overlooked the encoding within the binary data file: it is ISO-8859-1. *doh* Using Iconv I was able to successfully transcode: `var v = new Iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8'); v.convert(buf).toString('utf8');`.